# Equivalent SQL_NO_CACHE command in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I use `SQL_NO_CACHE` in MySQL for run query select without cache.

like this

`select SQL_NO_CACHE id from mytable`

Now I want to run an equivalent query in oracle.

I search in google but not found any things for run select without cache in oracle.

Comment: What does it do in MySQL?

Comment: SQL_NO_CACHE run select with out cache

Comment: What kind of cache? There is no way you can bypass the buffer cache in Oracle

Answer (score 3):

Query results are normally not cached in Oracle, only the requested table or index blocks. In Oracle 12 a result cache was introduced, that seems to be similar to the MySQL feature:

```
SELECT /*+ NO_RESULT_CACHE */ id
  FROM mytable;

SELECT /*+ RESULT_CACHE */ id
  FROM mytable;
```

More details are in Oracle's [Performance Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGDBA/tune_result_cache.htm#TGDBA647).

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan: Thanks, just saw that, too.